Why Spark independent Actions in Spark App / Notebook do not run in parallel standardly
In the past I was aware of the fact that that Actions in a Notebook or Spark App would run sequentially. Also, completely independent Actions. That is what I thought until someone stated on SO - cannot find  that anymore - that independent Actions can run in parallel in the same Spark App. That is not the case. Albeit I have seen Stages running in parallel some times.
I just re-tested this on a same Databricks Cluster Notebook as follows.

2 counts from 2 independently created RDD's. From The Stages tab I can see the submits occur in short succession and there is thus no parallel processing; it runs sequentially.

2 delta saveAsTable - they run sequentially. All logic is independent again.


So, why does Spark DAG processing not see - as it is lazily evaluated - that there are 2 independent Actions to run and allow for .par like processing internally?
Is there a parameter for this? No. chatGPT - dare I mention this - after much pushing, states that if there are enough resources it can make the decision to run parallel.
Seems a little odd that Futures or .par needed for completely independent Actions in same Spark App. Sure, Databricks WorkFlow Job Tasks can assist here, but.
